# How do I convert a JSON received on my Spring Kafka consumer into an entity ready to be saved in the bank?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I need to consume JSONs from Kafka topics and convert to entities, so I can save to the database, Postgres, in case

Consumer configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class ConsumerConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "Kafka");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(String.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public EventConsumer consumer() {
        return new EventConsumer();
    }
}
```

Consumer class:

```
@Slf4j
@Data
public class EventConsumer {
    private EntidadeComercialRepository entidadeComercialRepository;
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${topic.entidades_comerciais}")
    public void kafkaConsumer(@Payload EntidadesComerciais entidadesComerciais) {
        entidadeComercialRepository.save(entidadesComerciais);
        log.info("received payload='{}'", entidadesComerciais);
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Partial entity class

```
@lombok.Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "ENTIDADES_COMERCIAIS")
@Builder
public class EntidadesComerciais {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODIGO_DA_ENTIDADE_COMERCIAL")
    private Long codigoDaEntidadeComercial;

    @Column(name = "NOME_DA_ENTIDADE_COMERCIAL")
    private String nomeDaEntidadeComercial;

    @Column(name = "NOME_COMERCIAL")
    private String nomeComercial;

    @Column(name = "TIPO_DA_ENTIDADE_COMERCIAL")
    private String tipoDaEntidadeComercial;
    ...
```

Im using Spring Kafka and Postgres. When program is started, I receive this exception:

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void br.com.dchristofolli.kafka.EventConsumer.kafkaConsumer(br.com.dchristofolli.kafka.entity.EntidadesComerciais)]
Bean [EventConsumer(entidadeComercialRepository=null, latch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@144e36ae[Count = 1])]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [br.com.dchristofolli.kafka.entity.EntidadesComerciais] for GenericMessage [payload={"topic":"ENTIDADES_COMERCIAIS"...
```

I need to know what I did wrong, or if I need to modify any part of my code to be able to convert the payload received in my entity `ENTIDADES_COMERCIAIS` Thanks to anyone who can help me

Comment: Can you share a sample payload?

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [br.com.dchristofolli.kafka.entity.EntidadesComerciais

You are telling the deserializer to create a String instead of a `EntidadesComerciais`.

```
new JsonDeserializer<>(String.class)
```

Comment: And I guess that the key should be `new JsonDeserializer()` instead of `new StringDeserializer()`.

Comment: It depends on the type of the key; if it's a String, then `StringSerializer` is correct. If it's a complex object you might need JSON.

Comment: I assumed so because of this config: `properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);`

Comment: Ah - I didn't notice that; those properties are ignored when you add concrete instances to the constructor. You should configure one way or the other, to avoid confusion. To configure the default class you can use `JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE`.